# on tap of anchor tag unable to get href value in amp

Tags: amp-html

on tap of anchor tag unable to get href value in amp(i have use Birthday Card  even.value is working only for input element on change)

my question is how to get href value on tap of any anchor tag in amp page

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I got a thought I just add the dynamice value at linkval:dynamicvariable

now my my question is this linkval

i want to give in google-analytics code for method how??

example code:

```
 "triggers": {
            "button": {
              "selector": "#related-popup-link",
              "on": "click",
              "vars": {
                "event_name": "login",
                "method": linkval
              }
            }
          }
```

i did this but not working